# How exactly does stale data appear in temporal buffer in Downfall attack?

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems, security

I've read [Downfall paper](https://downfall.page/media/downfall.pdf). In the university, I've had an introductory course on computer organization and operating systems. We also studied Spectre and Meltdown attacks there. I understood the interplay of speculative execution and side channels in the case of those attacks.

I understand the general similarity between Downfall and Spectre/Meltdown. I understand how once stale data is accessed from temporal buffer it can be transported using a cache-based side channel.

What I don't understand is what exactly makes the access to stale data possible? Does the CPU continue executing instructions with stale data passed even when it is concluded that a new fetch is needed? Is the execution restarted upon completing the new data fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the CPU continue executing instructions with stale data passed even when it is concluded that a new fetch is needed?

Yes, that's right. This is the culprit in most of the attacks that are called *Spectre* or *MDS*, including this one. I think the best demonstration is the original Meltdown attack: you can just read some data you don't have permissions for. You can *just do that*, and the CPU doesn't stop you! The trick is to leak the data before the CPU does stop you, which is what the cache is used for.

The idea with MDS is very similar, but instead of directly reading data we shouldn't, we cause the CPU to load some data into some buffer and then use the buffer, but the load doesn't work and the next part of the instruction uses the old data from the buffer. Just like Meltdown, the CPU eventually stops you, but you can leak the data using the cache before that happens. Apparently, gather instructions can do this. Researchers keep finding more and more instructions that can trigger the same basic idea.

It seems to be a design decision of Intel CPUs that once an instruction faults, it will keep running instructions that have already been started, and then cancel their the effects so it looks like they didn't run. But the effects on the cache are not canceled, so the cache can be used to leak data.